# How to show the SVG content if I get SVG code in textarea using js

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm working on a drawing web app which can accept SVG content and show SVG image.
For example, user can input

```
<rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />"
```

into a textarea and the web will then show the SVG image.
I wonder is there function in JS that can do this?

Comment: Try something like this: `textarea.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  svg.innerHTML = textarea.value;
})`

Answer (score 0):

I found a lib for manipulating and animating SVG: SVG.js.

This command:

> `draw.svg()`

can exporting the full generated SVG.

Answer (score -1):

You need to show the image on a div with tag

and atualize the address of the src in javascript.